# Equality in proof of Theorem 14.9 from Harris's book

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, local-rings

In the book *Algebraic Geometry - A First Course* by Harris, it is given a proof for the following theorem:

> **Theorem 14.9.** Let $\pi:X\rightarrow Y$ be a finite map of varieties. Then $\pi$ is an isomorphism if and only if it is bijective and the map $d\pi:T_p(X)\rightarrow T_{\pi(p)}(Y)$ is an injection for all $p\in X$.

In the proof, they assume $X$ and $Y$ are affine and pass to an algebra question. By localizing at some maximal ideal, they get an integral extension of local rings $(A,\mathfrak{m})\subset(B,\mathfrak{n})$ where the map $\mathfrak{m}/\mathfrak{m}^2\rightarrow\mathfrak{n}/\mathfrak{n}^2$. Using Nakayama's lemma they get $\mathfrak{m}B=\mathfrak{n}$. Then they apply the same lemma together with $B=\mathfrak{n}+A$ to get $A=B$. My question is: why is $B$ equal to $\mathfrak{n}+A$? This is in general not true for finite extensions of local ring, but I don't see how they use the other information to get this equality.

Comment: Harris works over complex numbers and then the natural map $A\to B/\mathfrak{n}=\mathbb{C}$ is onto.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! So he just uses that $A$ and $B$ are algebras over an algebraically closed field.

Comment: Finite type algebras over an algebraically closed field and $\mathfrak{n}$ is a maximal ideal.

Comment: Can someone give a counterexample where $\pi$ is finite, bijective but the differential is not an injection?

Comment: @IoannisZolas your query would probably would fare better as a new question instead of a comment on this post. Anyways, a projection of a curve in $\Bbb P^3$ from a point on a tangent line should do the trick, I think?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a community wiki answer in order to record the discussion from the comments so that this question may be marked as answered (once this post is upvoted or accepted).

> Harris works over complex numbers and then the natural map $A\to B/\mathfrak{n}=\Bbb C$ is onto. – **Mohan**